# Multiple count() invocations with the same argument in one query

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table `persons`:

```
CREATE TABLE persons
(
     id INTEGER,
     age INTEGER,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Is there any difference between the following two queries?

Query #1:

```
SELECT age, count(*) 
FROM persons 
GROUP BY age 
ORDER BY count(*);
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT age, count(*) AS cnt 
FROM persons 
GROUP BY age 
ORDER BY cnt;
```

Will the first query actually `count()` twice, or will that be optimized away by the query planner? Does it depend on vendor or is it defined by the standard?

Comment: This will depend **highly** on what **concrete RDBMS** you're using. Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s Actually whether this will "depend highly on what concrete RDBMS" I'm using is also part of my question. So is query #2 a safer bet than #1?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Product specific question!

Comment: There won't be any difference for any modern DBMS. To be honest: I consider a DBMS that would count the rows twice to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Both the query will have same effect.

If you run both these query parallel ,Query cost is showing as same.

[image]

Comment: Is this behavior defined anywhere in standard SQL? (Does it depend on vendors?)

Comment: This is specific to SQL server engine and the that is decided by the query optimizer ..